# Is there a open source monitoring package that monitors logs for specific string patterns?

Tags: linux, unix, logging, monitoring

In our current system, we are not effectively monitoring the logs for errors as most of the errors are not serious enough. I want to basically warn users on the important errors. I cannot touch the code, so I cannot change these messages type to fatal.

So, I want to write scripts searching logs for the regex of the important error messages. Is there a opensource software package that does this?

Comment: Everything you need to do this is already inluded with Linux.A bash or perl script managed by a cron job would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with nagios.  The nrpe plugin allows you to execute custom scripts on a machine.  Such a script could easily parse a log and report back the results.

There are already many plugins so you may not need to write anything

Answer (score 0):

For general use (with system log for example), you can try out [yaala](http://www.yaala.org) or [petit](http://crunchtools.com/software/petit).